# A question about Lorentz transformations in spinor representation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry, group-representations, spinors

For

$$\Lambda^{\mu}{}_{\nu}= \frac{1}{2} Tr(\bar{\sigma}^{\mu} S \sigma_{\nu}S^{\dagger}) $$

We need to prove that

$$\Lambda (S)= \Lambda (-S)$$

Am I naive to say that by adding $-S$, $S^{\dagger}$ also changes sign thus the sign is always positive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can say that. $S \in SL(2,\mathbb{C})$, a particular $2\times2$-matrix. $S^\dagger$ is just the complex-conjugated transposed of $S$. And the complex-conjugated transposed of $-S$ is $-S^\dagger$.